# PayPal - CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile - is this request valid?

Tags: xml, payment-gateway, paypal

I sending this request to make a recurring paypent (SOAP request to SandBox),
but in response I get error message about missing token and other fields invalid (Missing Token or payment source).
What could be wrong with this **CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile** request?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
   xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"
   SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI"
SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
         <Credentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
            <Username>xxxxx_biz_api1.gmail.com</Username>
            <Password>xxxxxxx</Password>
            <Subject/>
         </Credentials>

      </RequesterCredentials>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
         <CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest>
            <Version
              xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"
              xsi:type="xsd:string">58.0</Version>



<CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails>

            <RecurringPaymentsProfileDetails xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">

            <BillingStartDate></BillingStartDate>
     </RecurringPaymentsProfileDetails>  

 <ScheduleDetails>
   <Description>Must match</Description>
   <PaymentPeriod>

    <BillingPeriod>Day</BillingPeriod>
    <BillingFrequency>1</BillingFrequency>

    <Amount>39.95</Amount>
   </PaymentPeriod>
 </ScheduleDetails>

        <Token>EC-480620864W522011V</Token>

 </CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails>
         </CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest>
      </CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq>

   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

P.S. I am sending this request the correct way, after "Doexpresscheckout" command.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

```
<CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails>
should be
<CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseDetailsType">
```